# How do I spawn enchanted armour with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to spawn armour using commands. I have tried the basic

```
/give @p diamond_chestplate 1 0 {Unbreakable:1,display...
```

But the problem is is that I can't get the enchantments on it. I want it to have Lvl 200 of all protections + thorns. I was thinking of adding the xtra stuff to the helm and boots.

Is this actually possible without an external software or an anvil?

Answer (score 2):

```
/give @p diamond_chestplate 1 0 {ench:[{id:0,lvl:200},{id:7,lvl:200}],HideFlags:4,Unbreakable:1}

/give @p diamond_leggings 1 0 {ench:[{id:0,lvl:200},{id:7,lvl:200}],HideFlags:4,Unbreakable:1}
```